# Error while using Control.Measure: no method 'setMap'

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have OpanLayers 2.10 an when I try to add the `OpenLayers.Control.Measure` to the map controls, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setMap'
```

This is my code:

```
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(
OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {
  persist: true
}));
```

*Note: I think my problem is related to the `OpenLayers.Handler.Path` because after debugging the code I figure out that the `CLASS_NAME` of the object is `OpenLayers.Handler.Path`.*

What's the problem with my code? Should I add specific module/plugin to the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. The problem is related to using Custom Build and priority of adding modules to main OpenLayers file.

I used `Control.Point` and `Control.Path` this way:

1. Control.Path
2. Control.Point

Which is incorrect and correct order/priority is:

1. Control.Point
2. Control.Path

Now, after changing the order of including OpenLayers modules, everything works fine.